# OleDbException: Could not update; currently locked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, ado.net, oledbexception

I am using .mdb database in ASP.NET MVC application.

I am inserting multiple rows within a for loop using transaction. In case of exception,  transaction is rollbacked & disposed. But if I try to insert after an exception, I am getting OleDbException `Could not update; currently locked.` Database table is not opened in design mode.

But if I close and re-open visual studio, and re-run the app, then it works fine.

Any clue?

Comment: Sounds like upon an exception being caught, the previous transaction is not being disposed properly and is therefore still trying to use the DB.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre, Thanks. Your assumption is correct. I missed to dispose transaction somewhere.

Comment: Show part of code which includes Access DB transaction/query (using `OleDbConnection`) in your question if necessary. I think you should close a database transaction even after an exception has triggered.